Download a file from Salesforce storage with CLI possible?
We need to transfer a lot of files (images, PDFs and so on) from Salesforce native storage to another storage, like Google Drive or Google Cloud Storage.
I've found the command that let me upload a file and set the parent:
sf data create file --file resources/astro.png --title AstroOnABoat.png --target-org my-scratch
(from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_data_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_data_create_file_unified)
But how can I download (or transfer) a file from native Salesforce storage?
And how can I set (or overwrite) a new URL or link for a given file with the cli?

Regarding downloads: I don't think the situation has changed with the introduction of sf and all of us doing ContentDocuments.
